# How to handle a possible uncatchable error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, error-handling, jsforce

I've got a very small program in index.js, it tries to make a connection to a URL that does not exist, and makes a request within that connection. When that happens I want to catch and handle any errors, but I'm getting an `ENOTFOUND` raised and it forces my program to exit. How do I go about catching this error and handling it properly?

Index.js:

```
const jsforce =  require("jsforce");


conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  accessToken: "",
  instanceUrl: "http://thisdoesnotexistalsdkfjalsdkfjasdlkfjasdlkfjalsdkfja.com",
  version: "51.0",
  callOptions: {
    client: `sf-fx-runtime-nodejs-sdk-impl-v1:1`
  }
});

const response = conn.query("SELECT foo from bar");
console.log(response);

response.then(
undefined,
function foo(e) {
  console.log("======================== lol")
  console.log(e)
})
```

Actual:

```
$ node index.js
/Users/rschneeman/Documents/projects/work/nodejs-uncatachable-error-maybe/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461
      reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${err.message}`, 'system', err));
             ^
FetchError: request to http://thisdoesnotexistalsdkfjalsdkfjasdlkfjasdlkfjalsdkfja.com/services/data/v51.0/query?q=SELECT%20foo%20from%20bar failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND thisdoesnotexistalsdkfjalsdkfjasdlkfjasdlkfjalsdkfja.com
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/rschneeman/Documents/projects/work/nodejs-uncatachable-error-maybe/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND'
}
```

Expected:

```
$ node index.js
======================== lol
      reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${err.message}`, 'system', err));
(logged but doesn't force exit the process)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug report for jsforce, not a question for StackOverflow :-) Your code is fine.

Answer (score -3):

Your case seems like a [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) situation. You can do something like:

```
try {
  //do stuff
catch (error) {
  //handle your error
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).